# Kollar Shepherd-Barron compactification of moduli spaces: a reference request.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

HI,  I am having some hard time finding a reference in this topic. I don't want to get right away into the Kollar's articles, because it can be a little too technical for me.  Do you know a good place to learn it? Like most people I did read Hartshorne, but also like most people I suffered it a lot. Of course, I do expect to  get into the full details, but I was hoping for some introduction and perspective.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you know about the book Kollár is writing?  
http://www.math.princeton.edu/~kollar/
Maybe that's what you meant though?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I was just wondering if there are short notes. In the style of Vakil's note about stable reduction: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/sm.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure, Maybe Sandor or Zsolt or VA would know better?

Answer (score 1):

The best introduction of Kollar Shepherd-Barron compactification of moduli spaces

appears [here](http://www.crm.cat/en/Activities/Documents/quadern-web.pdf) Advanced Course on
Compactifying Moduli Spaces